# Can I use LINQ First() and return null if no item is found?

Tags: c#, linq

I am traversing a list as follows:

```
var user = Userlist.FirstOrDefault(t => t.userId == currentUserId);
if (user != null)
{ 
    //do whatever 
}
```

If no element is found, it returns `null` and I can check for it.

But if I use .First(), it is a bit quicker. But if no element is found it gives a sequence error, Sequence contains no matching element

```
var user = Userlist.First(t => t.userId == currentUserId);
```

So, can I use the First() in LINQ, and if no element is found, do a check first before proceeding, because I found that First() is quicker?

Comment: Please provide data showing that First() is quicker than FirstOrDefault()

Comment: *it is a bit quicker* - how many nanoseconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `IEnumerable<T>.First()` **intentionally** throws an exception if no matching item is found in the enumerable. This is by design, and it is why the `FirstOrDefault()` extension exists.

`First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` should have very similar (if not the same) performance. They will both execute in O(n) time.

When you consider that `First()` will generate an exception if a matching element cannot be found, the performance hit from that exception will almost certainly be significantly worse than doing a null check. Null checks are extremely fast.